# Start-Process The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: powershell-3.0

Need some help to find the problem with the below.

The issue is around the $setup

Start-Process -workingdirectory c:\temp $setup -wait

```
        $storageDir = 'C:\Temp'
        $file = '1.1.1.1'
        $SpecIP = '192.168.0.87'
        $password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force
        $user = "User1"
        $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential    ($user,$password)
  $rsName =  'Responses.txt'
        $setup = "$file.exe $rsName"
```

The following works I hard code the value

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SpecIP -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
param($setup)
Start-Process -workingdirectory c:\temp 1.1.1.1 Responses.txt -wait
} -ArgumentList $setup
```

Not working the only different is the $setup

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SpecIP -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
param($setup)
Start-Process -workingdirectory c:\temp $setup -wait
} -ArgumentList $setup
```

Error

> This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCo 
>      mmand
>       + PSComputerName        : 192.168.0.87

Answer (score 8):

I found the issue. I needed to add a `.\` before the exe name.

```
$setup = ".\$dirchosen.exe $rsName"

Start-Process powershell -workingdirectory c:\temp "$setup" -wait
```